# C++: What's wrong with my use of Stringstream here?

Tags: c++, fstream, stringstream

I posted this program yesterday (in case you didn't see it yesterday, I re-posted a basic summary below), and you guys showed me what was wrong with my Boolean logic, so everything is working as I want it to, but I am processing the last line twice if I use something like while(inFile), or while(!inFile.eof()), etc. Because of this, I wanted to use stringstream, so that I can process the input line by line.

Since the input data is not just one data type (it is int, int, char, char, float), I used stringstream in the following way (as also shown in my code below):

```
while (getline(inFile, line)){

istringstream ss(line);

while(ss >> numAdults >> numChildren >> mealType >> dayType >> depositAmount){
```

These are my variables that I'm trying to read in my input file, in the correct order. What happens is that I get 4 lines of output in my billing_statement text file and 3 lines of output in the error_report text file (There are a total of 13 lines in the input text file). It seems like some of the lines might be combined. Appreciate the assistance here.

Thanks.

INPUT FILE:

10  0   S   Y   100.00

27  3   D   Y   57.50

125 17  D   N   0.00

4   0   S   N   25.00

0   25  S   Y   23.75

250 43  D   N   500.00

0   0   D   N   0.0

10  0   R   Y   10.00

17  3   D   R   15.00

5   0   D   Y   275.00

-3  10  D   Y   20.00

14  -1  S   N   30.00

20  3   D   Y   -10.00

Here is a link to my thread yesterday, which explains my program, although it shouldn't be needed for my specific question...

[C++: Mock Catering Company Billing Program - Not able to ouput bad data to error file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20306541/c-mock-catering-company-billing-program-not-able-to-ouput-bad-data-to-error)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

void getData(int &, int &, char &, char &, float &);
void checkValid(int &, int &, char &, char &, float &, bool &);
void calcData(int, int, char, char, float, float &, float &, float &, float &);
void sendData(int, int, char, char, float, float &, float &, float &, float &);

ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile("Billing_Statement.txt");
ofstream error_Report("Error_Report.txt");

//Declare the tax rate and weekend surcharge as constants.

const float taxRate = 0.18;
const float weekendSurcharge = .07;

int main()
{

bool valid = true;
float mealCost;
float totalTax;
float totalSurcharge;
float discountAmount;
int numAdults;
int numChildren;
char mealType;
char dayType;
float depositAmount;
string line;

cout << "\nThis program will calculate data for a catering company " << endl;

outFile << " Adults " << "Children  " << "Meal " << " Weekend " << setw(9) << "Deposit "
<< setw(6) << "Tax" << setw(11) << "Surcharge" << setw(10) << "Discount" << setw(12) << 
"Meal Cost" << endl;
error_Report << " Adults " << "Children  " << "Meal " << " Weekend " << setw(9) << 
"Deposit " << endl;

inFile.open("file.txt");

if (!inFile) {
cout << "\nError: File could not be opened. ";
//exit(1);
}

while (getline(inFile, line)){

istringstream ss(line);

while(ss >> numAdults >> numChildren >> mealType >> dayType >> depositAmount){
getData(numAdults, numChildren, mealType, dayType, depositAmount);
checkValid(numAdults, numChildren, mealType, dayType, depositAmount, valid);

if (valid == true)
{
    calcData(numAdults, numChildren, mealType, dayType, depositAmount, totalTax,
 totalSurcharge, discountAmount, mealCost);
    sendData(numAdults, numChildren, mealType, dayType, depositAmount, mealCost, 
totalTax, totalSurcharge, discountAmount);
}}
}

cout << "\nA copy of this has created for your convenience in the file, 
Billing_Statement.txt" << endl;

inFile.close();
outFile.close();
error_Report.close();

return 0;

}

void getData(int & numAdults, int & numChildren, char & mealType, char & dayType, float
& depositAmount)
{
inFile >> numAdults >> numChildren >> mealType >> dayType >> depositAmount;
}

void checkValid(int & numAdults, int & numChildren, char & mealType, char & dayType, 
float & depositAmount, bool & valid)
{

if (numAdults < 0 || numChildren < 0)
valid = false;
else if (!(mealType == 'D' || mealType == 'S'))
valid = false;
else if (!(dayType == 'Y' || dayType == 'N'))
valid = false;
else if (depositAmount < 0)
valid = false;

else
valid = true;

if (valid == false) {

error_Report << setw(7) << numAdults << setw(9) << numChildren << setw(6) << 
mealType << setw(9) << dayType << setw(9) << right << depositAmount << setw(8) << endl;
}
}

void calcData(int numAdults, int numChildren, char mealType, char dayType, float  
depositAmount, float & totalTax, float & totalSurcharge, float & discountAmount, float & 
mealCost)
{

if (mealType == 'S') {

mealCost = ((numAdults * 21.75) + (numChildren * (21.75 * .60)));
totalTax = mealCost * taxRate;
mealCost += taxRate;

if (dayType == 'Y') {
    totalSurcharge = mealCost * weekendSurcharge;
    mealCost += totalSurcharge;
}}

else {

mealCost = ((numAdults * 25.80) + (numChildren * (25.80 * .60)));
totalTax = mealCost * taxRate;
mealCost += taxRate;

if (dayType == 'Y') {
    totalSurcharge = mealCost * weekendSurcharge;
    mealCost += totalSurcharge;
    }
}

if (mealCost < 100) {

discountAmount = .015 * mealCost;
mealCost -= discountAmount;
}

else if (mealCost >= 100 && mealCost < 400) {

discountAmount = .025 * mealCost;
mealCost -= discountAmount;
}

else if (mealCost >= 400) {

discountAmount = .035 * mealCost;
mealCost -= discountAmount;
}
}

void sendData(int numAdults, int numChildren, char mealType, char dayType, float
depositAmount, float &mealCost, float &totalTax, float &totalSurcharge, float 
&discountAmount)
{
outFile << fixed << showpoint << setprecision(2);
outFile << setw(7) << numAdults << setw(9) << numChildren << setw(6) << mealType <<
setw(9) << dayType << setw(9) << right << depositAmount << setw(8) << totalTax << 
setw(10) << totalSurcharge << setw(10) << right << discountAmount << setw(12) << right 
<< mealCost << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `getData()` function is reading input from `inFile`: one line is read by `std::getline()` and the next line is read in `getData()`. It seems, `getData()` was meant to read the data which is actually read in the nested `while`. As it is right now, `getData()` is actually harmful. I would change the code to

1. Not use a nested `while`-loop but rather use an `if`-statement.
2. Print the line if it couldn't be read, i.e., in the `if`'s `else`-branch.
3. Remove the use and probably the implementation of `getData()`.
4. Indent the code to reflect its structure.
5. Of course, I [wouldn't use `std::endl`](http://kuhllib.com/2012/01/14/stop-excessive-use-of-stdendl/) but `'\n'`.
6. There is no need to `close()` files as the destructors of the respective streams will do so anyway (the only need to use `close()` is when you want to deal with errors).

Comment: Thank you - I can't believe I forgot about the getData function. Removing it, by itself, solved the problem for me. I am also concerned that I am overusing references - If so, could someone please point out when/if I am doing so?